# Composing the lighting of the object from several photos Python OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

My task is to combine all of pictures to one which is in the result.png. The task is that the object should be well illuminated as possible from all sides. I can't use any neural networks or other ML stuff. What methods or key words should I looking for?

I am using Python for this one, OpenCV, numpy etc. How would you do that? You can write me as pseudocode.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the attempt you have made so far, as well as some photos I can work with to properly debug or offer some methods?